# How to run and read cmd/git bash via python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a code that can auto run cmd/git bash based on user input. Then I need to read the result from cmd/git bash to complete the script. Any idea how? -tia

Comment: learn about `subprocess.Popen()`.  one note many people miss is that when reading its stdout pipe, you get `bytes` (in Python3), not `str` (string).

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

```
#From subprocess Docs: 

subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])  # doesn't capture output
CompletedProcess(args=['ls', '-l'], returncode=0)
```